# How to fix SQL Injection veracode issue- CWE 564

Tags: hibernate, veracode, secure-coding

```
@Override
public AssetLibraryReference selectALRefByName(String entityName,String name) throws Exception {
    AssetLibraryReference returnRef = null;
    String query = "from " + entityName + " where name = :name ";
    
    try {
        returnRef = sessionQueryUtil.doSessionQuery(session -> {
        //  queryStr.append("from " + entityName + " where name = :name ");             
            
          Query q =  session.createQuery(query);
                  q.setString("name", name);    
            
            
            return (AssetLibraryReference)q.uniqueResult();
        });
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        LOG.error ("Caught hibernate exception",e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Caught Exception :"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    return returnRef;
}
```

I'm getting veracode scan error at `Query q =  session.createQuery(query);`. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue. What can I use here to fix the issue. The veracode issue id is CWE 564.

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Comment: @RomanCanlas I've implemented the solution, waiting for the veracode report.

Comment: @RomanCanlas No brother, the solution didn't work out..

Comment: what was the latest Veracode scan result? Any changes in the finding or is it the same?

Comment: @RomanCanlas Yes I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query.setParameter instead, to make name a named parameter preventing SQL Injection

```
@Override
public AssetLibraryReference selectALRefByName(String entityName,String name) throws Exception {
    AssetLibraryReference returnRef = null;
    String query = "from " + entityName + " where name = :name ";
    
    try {
        returnRef = sessionQueryUtil.doSessionQuery(session -> {
        //  queryStr.append("from " + entityName + " where name = :name ");             
            
          Query q =  session.createQuery(query);
                  q.setParameter("name", name);    
            
            
            return (AssetLibraryReference)q.uniqueResult();
        });
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        LOG.error ("Caught hibernate exception",e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Caught Exception :"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    return returnRef;
}
```